# Why isn't this code for prop.test giving me the right answer for test statistics?

Tags: r, probability, hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, p-value

I have used the following line of code but it doesn't give me the right answer for (`chi-squared`) `test statistic` while it gives the right answer for `p-value` regarding the following question:
"Consider testing H_0: p = 0.5 against H_1: p ≠ 0.5, given that there were 38 successes in a sample of size 56. Find the value of the (chi-squared) test statistic. (Do not use the continuity correction.)"

```
> prop.test(38,n=56,p=1/2)
    1-sample proportions test with continuity correction

data:  38 out of 56, null probability 1/2
X-squared = 6.4464, df = 1, p-value = 0.01112
alternative hypothesis: true p is not equal to 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.5390880 0.7935168
sample estimates:
        p 
0.6785714
```

Can you give some explanation in your answers? I am not coming from a statistics background.

Comment: What does the last line of the question say? What does the first line of your output say? What does `?prop.test` say about continuity corrections?

Comment: If this is a homework question you should apply the self-study tag.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that I was using proportions test with `continuity correction` while in the question it was mentioned to use proportions test without continuity correction. So we just need to add `correct=FALSE` parameter to `prop.test` function.

```
> prop.test(38,n=56,p=1/2,correct=FALSE)

    1-sample proportions test without continuity correction

data:  38 out of 56, null probability 1/2
X-squared = 7.1429, df = 1, p-value = 0.007526
alternative hypothesis: true p is not equal to 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.5482264 0.7859901
sample estimates:
        p 
0.6785714
```